# CS-Cart Get Multi-Vendor vendor admin name on product page knowing $product.company_id

Tags: smarty, cs-cart

On a multivendor site, On the product page in CS-Cart I have access to many smarty variables but not to the Vendor Administrator's First and Last name.

Is there any way I can get that information knowing

```
{$product.company_id}
```

Answer (score 0):

There may be several administrators in the MVE edition. So you cannot get the First/Last name of 'company'. You can get a list of administrators and then get names.

Use the **fn_get_users** function with the specified company_id parameter.

```
$params = array(
    'company_id' => '3',
    'user_type' => 'V',
);
$vendor_admins = fn_get_users($params, $auth); // <- $_SESSION['auth']
```

To avoid duplicating requests for each product, you can modify the fn_get_companies function via hooks and add some new fields (First/Last names of Vendors) to the response.